# Попытка подсчетать количество элементов получаемых от API

Tags: android, kotlin

Продолжение вопроса. Начало [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/963189/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-api-json?noredirect=1#comment1612850_963189)

Вернул код в рабочее состояние. Код описания запроса:

```
const val GET_FEARDY_ID = 0

@Entity(tableName = "get_Ready")
data class GetReady(
    val adult: Int,
    @SerializedName("book_id")
    val bookId: Int,
    @SerializedName("id")
    val idGlavs: Int,
    val img: String,
    val lang: String,
    val rating: Double,
    @SerializedName("ready_date")
    val readyDate: String,
    @SerializedName("s_title")
    val sTitle: String,
    @SerializedName("t_title")
    val tTitle: String,
    val title: String
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    var id_Ready: Int = GET_FEARDY_ID
}
```

Код запуска:

```
@Query("select * from get_Ready where id_Ready = $GET_FEARDY_ID")
fun getListRadyDao(): LiveData<List<ImperialListReady>>
```

Решил отследить как работает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И тут видно, что количество элементов, приходит 1. 
Я пытался подсчитать:

```
     @Query("select  count(title) from get_Ready where idGlavs(idGlavs) >= idGlavs(:startDate)")      
 fun countFutureWeather(startDate: LocalDate): Int
```

Но после этого у меня приходит целый букет ошибок, появляющихся в целой цепочке.
Можете подсказать, в какую сторону искать и читать, любую информацию, буду благодарен.

Comment: Читайте ошибку, она говорит, что параметр `:startDate` не может в таком виде использоваться. Откуда у вас там вообще дата, если в таблице никаких дат нет? Напишите в вопросе ЧТО вы пытаетесь считать. Мне не понято.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Я пытаюсь считать, количество приходящих элементов, что бы вывести в ListView. Так как когда я вывожу его сейчас, у меня появляется только самый первый. Я думал, если посчтитать количество приходящих, idBook и отправить это количество в метод отображения ListView. То у меня будут отображаться все элементы.